# Adding Facebook and Twitter sharing to CartoDB infowindows?

Tags: carto, twitter, facebook

Trying to add share buttons to output something like:

```
{{region}} text {{region_variable}} text www.google.com
```

The below works very intermittently for Twitter, but when I share the URL, the map won't load.

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" target="_blank" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://www.google.com" data-text="{{region}} text {{region_variable}} text" data-count="none">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
```

Not even sure where to start with doing the same with Facebook.

Answer (score 3):

For the moment CartoDB do not support javascript in infowindow templates. In the meantime you can take a look to this blogpost:

http://blog.cartodb.com/introducing-social-infowindows-display-your-tweets-the/